# Possibility of using an existing SVM classifier (created with python) in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, classification, svm

I created using python an SVM classifier, trained it and exported it :

```
X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = train_test_split(...)
clf = svm.SVC(gamma='scale',kernel='rbf',C=1)
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
joblib.dump(clf, 'SVM_model.pk1', compress=9)
```

How can I leverage this SVM_model classifier in JavaScript (google chrome extension) for real prediction ? can I load it and give it the extracted data ? 
I do realize it's possible using XMLHttpRequest to send data from JavaScript to my python script to treat the extracted data and send back the result to the extension  but it's making the extension slow

Alternatively, if I'm obliged to create the classifier using JavaScript, how can I make it persistent ? how to export it ?

Many thanks

Comment: You can compile it into JavaScript. Or run it separately and communicate via nativeMessaging API. See the documentation.